# Prove that if an upper triangular matrix $A\in T_n(\mathbb{F})$ is invertible, then $A_{ii}\neq 0$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to prove that if an upper triangular matrix $A\in T_n(\mathbb{F})$ is invertible, then $A_{ii}\neq 0$ for $i=1,...,n$.

I know that this would be easiest to prove using a definition of the determinant, but we haven't covered that in class yet so I am not supposed to use it.

This is a proof I have written- I feel that it is somewhat flawed or not thorough enough, but I can't figure out how to improve it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Let $A\in T_n(\mathbb{F})$ where $A$ is invertible. Additionally, let $x_{ii}=0$ for some $x_{ii}\in A$ with $1\leq i\leq n$. Because $A$ is invertible, it represents a bijective linear transformation $T:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^n$. In particular, because this transformation is bijective, it is one-to-one, and so the kernel of $T$ is trivial, which implies linear independence of the columns of the matrix. Because $A$ is an upper triangular matrix, its diagonal entries represent a linearly independent set of vectors. Thus, for $c_j\in\mathbb{F}$ with $1\leq j\leq n$, if $c_1x_{11}+c_2x_{22}+...+c_ix_{ii}+...+c_nx_{nn}=0$, then $c_1=c_2=...=c_i=...=c_n=0$. However, because $x_{ii}=0$, we can have that $c_i\neq 0$ and $c_ix_{ii}=c_i\cdot 0=0$, so $c_1x_{11}+c_2x_{22}+...+c_ix_{ii}+...+c_nx_{nn}=0$ for any value of $c_i$. This means that our set of vectors is no longer linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "Because $A$ is an upper triangular matrix, its diagonal entries represent a linearly independent set of vectors". However, here's a hint to another way of proof: consider the row canonical form of $A$.

Comment: See that $$Rang A = n$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $RangA=n$? If this is the same $n$ that I have defined, I don't see how this is true. Do you mean that the range is $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

If the upper triangular matrix $A$ is invertible, then $det A \not = 0$, and since $det A = \prod_i^n A_{i,i}$ for an upper triangular matrix, $A_{i,i} \not = 0$ for any $i$.

**Edit:**

I have read your proof, and after and I think there is no flow. Plus, I think after stating that the diagonal entries on a fixed basis represents a linearly independent set, you can directly say that none of the entries can be zero, but of course if you have just started this kind of thing, it is quite reasonable to show that a set containing the zero vector cannot be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have less than n pivots, then the sistem $ Ax=e_i$ does not have unic solution. I think this must solve the problem.

Write me if you have some doubt